# Class with all possible methods defined/catched

Tags: python, class

I was trying to put together a stringIO-like function, and I was wondering if it was possible to build a class that catches all possible methods, so that the following would work:

```
a = magicclass("Hello World!") #Hello world would be the return
print a() #Would print Hello world
print a.read() #should also print hello world
print a.adsf.asdf.xyz.random() #should also print hello world
```

I have no real idea how to go by this, I could define all the possible methods I want to call, but that'd be problematic if I want to pass this to a black box function.

```
#This works, but only for the main method.
#Every submethod has to have its own class defined, if you know what I mean.
def emptyreturnfunc(returnval): lambda: returnval
b = emptyreturnfunc("Hello World")
print b() #Does work
print b.asdf() #Doesn't work.
```

I know why this is, of course, but how can I try to make it work? Any hints?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self, msg):
        self.msg = msg

    def __call__(self):
        print self.msg

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return self


a = A('Hello World')
a()
a.b()
a.b.c()
```

Comment: Nice and interesting solution.

Comment: A very nice solution indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Although the OP accepted this, it's only _almost_ what they asked for...to fix that I think `__call__` should `return self.msg`.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at the [Mock library](http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/), you'll see an example of something that basically implements the pattern that I think you are looking for.  However, outside of a mocking library, this is somewhat dangerous behavior.